# How to convert string to TPenStyle?

Tags: delphi

I saw some very similar threads here, but I couldn't find solution to my problem. 
I take the value from `TStringList` and use it as pen style (`psDot`, `psSolid` and so on), but the compilation fails with `Incompatible types: 'TPenStyle' and 'String'` error message.

Here is the code:

```
Image1.Canvas.Pen.Style := myList.ValueFromIndex[j];
```

How can I convert `myList.ValueFromIndex[j]` to `TPenStyle` ?

Comment: How do the strings look? Do you have `'psDot'` and so on? If that's the case you can use `GetEnumValue` from the `TypInfo` unit.

Comment: Where's the code that put it in mylist?

Comment: Style=psSolid
Rectangle=201,319,485,209
Style=psDash
Rectangle=13,15,181,78
Rectangle=206,12,403,75
Rectangle=446,9,639,74
Rectangle=28,95,247,190 - something like this is in myList

Comment: @Borlv: No need to change title when the issue is solved. That's implied by the existance of an accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if stored as psDot, psSolid else you have to adapt

```
uses TypInfo;

Image1.Canvas.Pen.Style := TPenStyle(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TPenStyle),myList.ValueFromIndex[j]));
```

as suggested by David Heffernan

```
Function PenStyleFromName(const Name: string):TPenStyle;
begin
  Result := TPenStyle(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TPenStyle),Name));
end;

//....
Image1.Canvas.Pen.Style := PenStyleFromName(myList.ValueFromIndex[j]);
```

Comment: +1 but the answer would be much better if you wrote it out as a function. You wouldn't want to write it like that in real code. Far too many concerns mixed in together. I'd write `function PenStyleFromName(const Name: string): TPenStyle` and put that implementation inside.